# Is "become 10°C" correct?

Tags: verbs

> 1. Turn off the switch when the temperature becomes 10°C.
> 2. Turn off the switch when the temperature becomes **equal to** 10°C.

Out of the two sentences I created, I think the second is better, but redundant.  Is the first sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but not at all idiomatic. Instead, I would say "...when the temperature **reaches** 10°C."

Comment: Can "reach" be used not only when the temperature increases to 10°C but also when the temperature decreases to 10°C ?

Comment: @rama9 Yes, it works either way. Also, "when the temperature _gets to_ 10°C" is a less formal version of the same thing (and replaces _reaches_ in a number of other contexts as well).

Comment: "When this baby hits 88..."

Comment: For a decrease, you could also use 'drops to 10°C'.